# Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery / allowEditing size

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

When a user loads a photo from the Gallery (or camera) if allowEditing is true, they can crop the image to fit a square.

Is it possible to change the height/width of that box, so instead of a square, it can be a rectangle?

[Screenshot of the square I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzQ8L.jpg)

Comment: Found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here to solve this, when you open the Gallery using `openPhotoGallery()` or the Camera using `showCamera()` you have access to two properties you can use:

1) `overlay` which is a `Ti.UI.View` where as the property name indicates you can add a view to the camera UI on top, this way you can make it any shape you want, and adjust it to the media present when returned. (I would personally use this implementation)

2) `transform` that lets you apply a transformation matrix to the cameras UI and you should be able to modify the bounding box.